# Crash on iOS-Simulator

Tags: ios, flutter

The app automatically closes once I click the location button at the top right on flutter ios simulator.

Device: iOS-Simulator (IPhone 11 Pro).

This is what shows on the terminal.

```
Lost connection to device.
*** First throw call stack:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e6aefe __exceptionPreprocess + 350
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff515339b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e6ad3c +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
        3   location                            0x000000010384f88a -[LocationPlugin requestPermission] + 426
        4   location                            0x000000010384ef18 -[LocationPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] + 2072
        5   Flutter                             0x0000000101332b1f __45-[FlutterMethodChannel setMethodCallHandler:]_block_invoke + 104
        6   Flutter                             0x00000001012c1762 _ZNK7flutter21PlatformMessageRouter21HandlePlatformMess<…>
```

[image: Here is the image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash says `[LocationPlugin requestPermission]`, this happened because you did not add the location permissions to your info.plist.

To solve this you need to
Add the location permissions to your info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>When in use permissions</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>always permissions</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUsageDescription</key>
<string>Always and in usage permissions</string>
```